Android keyboard that recognizes typos instead of adding them to autocorrect?
I want an Android virtual keyboard that can identify typos and simply never suggest them, instead of adding them to autocorrect lists. I want this especially when entering a sentence like "5his is typed it has context but it still thinks 5he is correct grammar/spelling."
When typing 5he instead of the and pressing enter, both Microsoft's SwiftKey and Google's Gboard keyboards add the obvious typo to the autocorrect list, which is not what I want.
Does such a keyboard exist? If not, does one exist that allows me to permanently block nonsensical autocorrects like this?
I don't mind misspelling it once, but if I remove it, I want it gone for good.

I use SwiftKey and when I make a typo and mistakenly save the word, what I do is write the misspelled word again for it to show in the auto-predict, I long press on it and SwiftKey asks me "Do you want to remove this word?" and I tap "Yes".

The issue is if you remove it and make the mistake again it adds it back. It would be nice if you could permanently remove it from being added.
